# finding multi column duplicates mysql

Tags: mysql

How can i find the duplicate records for multi column ? Table has primary key (Auto increment)

EG

```
 ID  a_id  b_id
 ---- ---- ------
   1    34   23
   2    34   23
   3    35   25
```

for example i want to find records with same a_id and b_id...

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select t.ID, t.a_id, t.b_id
from (
  select a_id, b_id
  from tbl
  group by a_id, b_id
  having count(*) > 1) x, tbl t
where x.a_id = t.a_id and x.b_id = t.b_id
order by t.a_id, t.b_id
```

This query will show you all the duplicates on the tuple (a_id, b_id)

Comment: Works great for me too. How do you have exactly one left, so in RULE101's example his table would be ID #2 and ID#3, when using DELETE?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT r1.id, r2.id
FROM test r1, test r2
WHERE r1.id < r2.id
AND r1.a_id = r2.a_id
AND r1.b_id = r2.b_id
```

Comment: +1 Nice and simple, old-school self-join, the r1.id < r2.id (instead of r1.id <> r2.id) will make sure you only get one hit per set of conflicting rows (if you don't do this you will get 2 rows for the same conflicting rows in your resultset).

Comment: i cant actually understand this

Comment: It's a self-join, maybe (if you only know join-syntax) it makes more sense if you rewrite it as follows `SELECT r1.id, r2.id, r1.a_id, r1.b_id FROM test r1 INNER JOIN test r2 ON r2.a_id=r1.a_id AND r2.b_id=r1.b_id WHERE r1.id < r2.id`

Comment: it is getting weird when duplicates more than 2 :/

Comment: @wimvds This "simple" costs about O(N^2) when a HAVING clause only needs O(N).

Answer (score 0):

**edit:**

Misread what you were looking for. You can find duplicate entries on your table using the group by argument for select as stated above or even a self join.

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM my_table;
+------+------+------+
| ID   | a_id | b_id |
+------+------+------+
|    1 |   34 |   23 |
|    2 |   34 |   23 |
|    3 |   35 |   25 |
+------+------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT t1.ID source_row, 
    ->        t2.ID same_as_row, 
    ->        t1.a_id a_id, 
    ->        t1.b_id b_id 
    ->   FROM my_table t1 
    ->   JOIN my_table t2 
    ->     ON t1.a_id = t2.a_id 
    ->    AND t1.b_id = t2.b_id 
    ->    AND t1.ID != t2.ID;

+------------+-------------+------+------+
| source_row | same_as_row | a_id | b_id |
+------------+-------------+------+------+
|          2 |           1 |   34 |   23 |
|          1 |           2 |   34 |   23 |
+------------+-------------+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**edit2:**

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM my_table;
+------+------+------+
| ID   | a_id | b_id |
+------+------+------+
|    1 |   34 |   23 | # same as 2, 4
|    2 |   34 |   23 | # same as 1, 4
|    3 |   35 |   25 |
|    4 |   34 |   23 | # same as 1, 2
|    5 |   31 |   23 |
+------+------+------+

mysql>   SELECT t1.ID source_row, 
    ->          t2.ID same_as_row, 
    ->          t1.a_id a_id, 
    ->          t1.b_id b_id 
    ->     FROM my_table t1 
    ->     JOIN my_table t2 
    ->       ON t1.a_id = t2.a_id 
    ->      AND t1.b_id = t2.b_id 
    ->      AND t1.ID != t2.ID
    -> ORDER BY source_row;
+------------+-------------+------+------+
| source_row | same_as_row | a_id | b_id |
+------------+-------------+------+------+
|          1 |           2 |   34 |   23 |
|          1 |           4 |   34 |   23 |
|          2 |           1 |   34 |   23 |
|          2 |           4 |   34 |   23 |
|          4 |           1 |   34 |   23 |
|          4 |           2 |   34 |   23 |
+------------+-------------+------+------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: When you use `t1.ID != t2.ID` you will get 2 results for the same conflict (which is clear from your example), to prevent this from happening you should use `t1.ID < t2.ID` (or `t1.ID > t2.ID` of course :p).

Comment: i left it like that so you can see both and choose which row you want to delete. it wasn't specified that the first, middle, last duplicate should be selected. However this gets strange when you have more than 2 duplicates. It will start listing the source row multiple times with each duplicate after. see edit.

Comment: yeah i got 28 results even though there are 8 duplicate rows

Answer (score -1):

It's a basic SQL query :

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE a_id = b_id;
```

where my_table is the name of your table.