# remove duplicates in mysql database

Tags: mysql

I have a table with columns latitude and longitude.  In most cases the value extends past the decimal quite a bit:  -81.7770051972473  on the rare occasion the value is like this: -81.77 for some records.

How do I find duplicates and remove one of the duplicates for only the records that extend beyond two decimal places?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using some creative `substring`, `float`, and `charindex` logic, I came up with this:

```
delete l1
from 
    latlong l1
    inner join (
        select
            id,
            substring(cast(latitude as varchar), 0, INSTR(CAST(latitude as varchar))+3, '.') as truncatedLat
        from
            latlong
    ) l2 on
        l1.id <> l2.id
        and l1.latitude = cast(l2.truncatedLat as float)
```

Before running, try `select *` in lieu of `delete l1` first to make sure you're deleting the right rows.

I should note that this worked on SQL Server using functions I know exist in MySQL, but I wasn't able to test it against a MySQL instance, so there may be some little tweaking that needs to be done. For example, in SQL Server, I used `charindex` instead of `instr`, but both should work similarly.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how to do that purely in SQL.

I have used scripting languages like PHP or CFML to solve similar needs by building a query to pull the records then looping over the record set and performing some comparison.  If true, then VERY CAREFULLY call another function, passing in the record ID and delete the record.  I would probably even leave the record in the table, but mark some another column as isDeleted.

If you are more ambitious than I, it looks like this thread is close to what you want

[Deleting Duplicates in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176686/deleting-duplicates-in-mysql)

[finding multi column duplicates mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456471/finding-multi-column-duplicates-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

Using an external programming language (Perl, PHP, Java, Assembly...):

- Select * from database
- For each row, select * from database where newLat >= round(oldLat,2) and newLat < round(oldLat,2) + .01 and //same criteria for longitude
- Keep one of them based on whatever criteria you choose. If lowest primary key, sort by that and skip the first result.
- Delete everything else.
- Repeat skipping to this step for any records you already deleted.

If for some reason you want to identify everything with greater than 2 digit precision:

```
select * from database where lat != round(lat,2), or long != round(long,2)
```